# How to initiate my own sequence of code when titleChanged event occurs in QWebView in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, events, browser, qwebview

I am new to Qt and I have been trying to develop a web browser for desktop. I have got the hang of the GUI designing of my web browser, but I have only started to learn this new language.

My question is: how do I execute my own sequence of code when the titleChanged event of the QWebView occurs?

Seriously speaking, I have no idea how to do this, which is why I cannot post any code. But, can someone please post the code for accomplishing my target.
You can assume that I have a class called MainWindow, in which I have added the QWebView from the Qt designer.

If I am unclear then please let me know.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QWebView::titleChanged` is a signal, not an event. Go to Qt Designer, open context menu of your QWebView element, choose `titleChanged` signal. It will create a slot in your MainWindow class.

Using signals and slots is one of the most basic techniques used in Qt. Please read [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) carefuly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am coming from C# to Qt, so I thought it would be called an event in Qt as well.